# Google Admin SDK getting 403 Insufficient Permissions error

Tags: php, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-groups, google-groups-api

I've created a service account and given it's client ID the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group` When I run the following code, I get a 403 error: Insuffient Permission.

```
<?php
// Requires >= PHP 5.4

require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

$settings = [
    'creds_path' => '/path/to/service_creds.json',
    'group_email' => 'group@email.com',
    'service_email' => 'service@email.com'
];

putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS={$settings['creds_path']}");

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP);
// $client->setSubject('admin@email.com');

$service = new Google_Service_Groupssettings($client);

try {
    print_r($service->groups->get($settings['group_email'], ['alt' => 'json']));
} catch(Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    if($e->getCode() == 404) {
        echo "Group {$settings['group_email']} not found.\n";
        exit;
    } elseif($e->getCode() == 403) {
        echo "Insufficient Permissions.\n";
        exit;
    } else {
        throw  $e;
    }
}
```

I read somewhere that the service account has to impersonate someone who has access to the admin sdk, so that's what the commented out line tried, but it didn't work.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

The code that's being `required` is from https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being that I was using the wrong class.  I switched `Google_Service_Groupssettings` to `Google_Service_Directory` and un-commented the `setSubject` call and now it works.